# How to retrieve the text value from RichText widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, richtext

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to retrieve just the text value from RichText widget.

```
String isRequiredMark(){
widget.textIsRequiredMark = RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
      TextSpan(text: 'World', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
);
return widget.textIsRequiredMark;
}
```

Please note that `widget.textIsRequiredMark` is a normal variable that's already been declared.

I want to retrieve the text value of this RichText widget as a String.
Is there aw ay to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `InlineSpan` using the `text` property and then call [`toPlainText()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan/toPlainText.html) on it:

```dart
widget.textIsRequiredMark.text.toPlainText();
```